# Android: How to write to the Android/data/app.path/files directory

Tags: android, android-emulator

So I want to write data to a file in a location that users can access it manually. The goal is to provide an easy-to-access crash log that I can be sent, without folks having to do a full logcat.

The one location on the internal storage filesystem that I'm aware of that can be written to by my app is `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my.app.package/files`. My goal, however, is to have this path be as platform-independent as possible.

I can get the `/storage/emulated/0` part using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. It's the Android/data/my.app.package/files part that I'm concerned about. I want to avoid hardcoded paths to avoid differences between devices.

So is there any utility method out there that can help me? I've tried `Context.getFilesDir()`, but that just gives me `/data/user/0/my.app.package`, which isn't accessible to the user without root.

Comment: What about getExternalStoragePublicDirectory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getExternalFilesDir` is what you want to use 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Writing Function i mostly use is

```
public static void writeStringAsFile(Context context, String fileContents, String fileName) {
    try {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + fileName));
        out.write(fileContents);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

and The path of package is like

```
String basePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/" +
            getPackageName().toString();
```

Modify or combine them as you wish.
PS : Don't Forget Permission :)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```